# Select last value in SQL table with conditions

Tags: mysql

i have a sample data like this:

[image]

Now i want to get lastest data used to have user_id = 41 and highest price, output like this:

[image]

How can i do it with SQL command line ?

Thank for read

Comment: is your output is correct as you are saying that user_id=41 but output is showing 42 even 2 times.

Comment: your conditions and your sample output doesn't match

Comment: may be my 2nd query fulfull your output requirement if I am able to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
select User_id,auction_id,price from tablename where price in(select price from tablename where id in(select max(id) from tablename group by user_id))
```

Comment: Oh ! Thank you very much ! Working !

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated output incorrectly then try it as per your provided conditions-

```
select user_id,auction_id,price 
from mytable 
where user_id=41 
order by auction_id;
```

But if as per your output you want 1 latest row of user_id=41 and then all rows of highest price then you can try it-

```
SELECT user_id,auction_id,price 
FROM mytable 
WHERE user_id=41 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 
UNION 
SELECT b.user_id,b.auction_id,price 
FROM mytable b 
JOIN (
SELECT MAX(price) AS price 
FROM mytable
) a ON a.price=b.price;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your output that you wish try this:

```
select user_id,auction_id,price 
from table_name 
where user_id=41 
order by id desc;
```